# список (тег <li></li>) кликабельный без ссылки (тега <a></a>)

Tags: html, css, blazor

Мне надо оставить список, то есть работать с тегом **li**.

Возможно ли сделать элемент списка кликабельным без добавления тега

`<a></a>` ?

```css
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  width: 12em;
  color: black;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #edebeb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">спискок кликабельный</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

тег blazor добавила, потому что веб проект блазор, c#, возможно есть событие, которое можно приписать к списку, или еще что то мне незнакомое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по нормам MDN не рекомендуется, но если все же нужно, то так:

```css
.listdetail-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  width: 12em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.listdetail-item:hover,
listdetail-item:active {
  background-color: #edebeb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li onclick="location.href = '#'" class="listdetail-item"> спискок кликабельный </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582588/13754729)

[документация MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes)

> Предупреждение. Использование атрибутов содержимого обработчика
> событий не рекомендуется. Сочетание HTML и JavaScript часто приводит к
> созданию неподдерживаемого кода, а выполнение атрибутов обработчика
> событий также может быть заблокировано политиками безопасности
> контента.

Answer (score 0):

Или так

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
}

.list__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.list__container > *::before {
  content: '•';
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.list__container > * + * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list__container">
  <a href="/путь" class="list__link">/путь</a>
  <a href="/путь" class="list__link">/путь</a>
  <a href="/путь" class="list__link">/путь</a>
</div>
```